# Get last value of group and set that value to the next group

Tags: python, pandas

The format of my dataset is like below:

```
>>> df
    race_year race_id driver_id driver_standings_position
    2007      1       1         5
    2007      1       2         4
    2007      2       1         3
    2007      2       2         7
    2007      3       1         2
    2007      3       2         5
    2008      4       1         1
    2008      4       2         3        
    2008      5       1         2                        
    2008      5       2         1                         
    2008      6       1         3                
    2008      6       2         2
```

What I want to achieve is this: 
I want the last years final championship position of driver x to be shows in a new column throughout the whole season.
Something like this:

```
>>> df
    race_year race_id driver_id driver_standings_position championship_position_last_year
    2007      1       1         5
    2007      1       2         4
    2007      2       1         3
    2007      2       2         7
    2007      3       1         2
    2007      3       2         5
    2008      4       1         1                         2
    2008      4       2         3                         5
    2008      5       1         2                         2
    2008      5       2         1                         5
    2008      6       1         3                         2
    2008      6       2         2                         5
```

I solved it like this:

```
test = df[['race_year','race_id','driver_id','driver_standings_position']].copy()
test['race_year'] += +1
test['driver_standings_position_last_year'] = test.groupby(['race_year','driver_id'])\
    ['driver_standings_position'].tail(1)
test

a = test.groupby(['race_year','driver_id'])
a = a.last()
b = a.reset_index()
df= pd.merge(df, b, how="left", left_on=['race_year',"driver_id"], right_on=['race_year',"driver_id"])

# Drop Columns
df= df.drop(columns=['race_id_y', 'driver_standings_position_y'])

# Rename Columns
df= df.rename(columns={"race_id_x": "race_id", "driver_standings_position_x": "driver_standings_position"})
```

But I am interested in a better/more convenient/pythonic way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from computing the following auxiliary DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['race_year', 'driver_id']).driver_standings_position\
    .last().rename('championship_position_last_year').reset_index()
```

It holds the championship position of each driver in the **current** year.

To change it to the position in the **last** (previous) year, run:

```
df2.race_year += 1
```

And to compute the final result, run:

```
df.merge(df2, how='left', on=['race_year', 'driver_id']).fillna('')
```

The above solution is to some extent similar to yours, but it is
shorter and (IMHO) more pandasonic.